# Swagger UI display generated client

Tags: c#, rest, swagger, nswag

There is swagger and there is nswag.

NSwag does some [client generation](https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag/blob/master/src/NSwag.Sample.NetCoreAngular/nswag.json).

Is it possible to generate client and display it as a link on Swagger UI for the consumers to download and use it?

Comment: You can simply add a download link to the `info.description` section of your API definition. Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost certainly not out the box. But then... you don't necessarily know what technology your client will choose. NSwag will generate a number of different types of clients in just a few minutes with little more effort than pointing it at the JSON Swagger definition (which Swagger/Swashbuckle automatically produces for your API), and is free to download; why not just let them do it?

You *could* speculatively generate a C# client for them and host it on your API server and serve it as say a zip file, but I don't really see the point, plus you'd have to make various customisation decisions for them, that they might prefer to make for themselves (namespace, HttpClient injection, partial class usage, etc).